# Selecting either keyboard or picker?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to show either a Picker or a keyboard depending upon the units selected.

For metric it's a keyboard so the user can enter say 300g whereas for imperial it's a picker so the user can select say 3 2/3 cups.

The picker shows but I cannot get the keyboard to not show.  resignFirstResponder does not work - as I assume it's not first responder.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

switch (_Unit) {
    case 1: // metric - show the keyboard
        [self unitHidePicker:nil];
        break;
        
    case 2: // oz & fl/oz
        
        [self unitShowPicker];
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        break;

    case 3: // US Cups
        [self unitShowPicker];
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        break;
}

return YES;
}
```

Comment: I spent about three hours trying to figure this out and about 10 mins after posting it did.  I need to return NO not to have the Keyboard and YES to have one.  So I just set a bool and it worked.

Comment: Though I would mention that, if it's what you're looking for, you can also set a picker as the inputView property of your textField.

Comment: @geraldWilliam thanks.  The problem was flipping between the two depending upon the selected unit.  But if nothing else, I learnt a lot in the past few hours :)

Answer (score 0):

The  most easiest way,use a button while showing UIPickerview and otherwise show a textField.The keyboard show hide is a mess.You can add a button and a textfield and switch showing them both and get the work done

OR
Set the `Return NO;` **inside the case loop** where you want to work the picker